# Consulta usando WHERE

Tags: mysql, select, sintaxe, where

Preciso fazer uma consulta em uma tabela chamada controles:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a coluna `CH` que é a carga horária em minutos e tenho a coluna `SETOR` que são os setores que participaram de algum treinamento.

Preciso fazer uma consulta onde me traz o total (soma) de minutos por setor. O setor 7 seria por exemplo `1080` o resultado.

Fiz assim: `SELECT round(SUM(ch)) FROM controles WHERE setor = '7';`

porem não me trás resultado algum.

Comment: Qual o tipo do seu campo `setor`?

Comment: Em primeiro lugar terá de separar os valores do setor de forma a se tornarem independentes. Ou seja, em que seja possível fazer uma pesquisa por ','. Por exemplo o array ficar com o seguinte aspeto: 2,3,4,5. Depois penso que será o "LIKE"  e não o = a ser usado... pode ser pouca ajuda, mas ajuda no raciocínio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer encontrar todos os registros onde o campo `setor` possui determinado número você teria que fazer assim:

Obs.: Entendendo que seu campo seja Varchar ou algum outro equivalente ao tipo de texto (String).

```
SELECT round(SUM(ch)) FROM controles WHERE setor like '%"7"%';
```

**Explicando**

*Exemplo 1*

```
Select * from Tabela where nome LIKE ‘a%’;
```

> O caráter acima ‘%’ indica que estamos buscando todos os
>   nomes que Iniciam com a letra ‘a’.

*Exemplo 2*

```
Select * from Tabela where nome LIKE ‘%a’;
```

> O carácter acima ‘%’ indica que estamos buscando todos
>   os nomes que tem a ultima letra ‘a’.

*Exemplo 3*

```
Select * from Tabela where nome LIKE ‘%a%’;
```

> Os dois carácteres acima ‘%’ indica que estamos buscando todos
>   os nomes que tem a letra ‘a’ em qualquer parte do texto.

Comment: Os dados informados pelo AP estão assim ["2","7","17","97","87"], seu like %7% não iria pegar os dados errados não ?

Comment: @PedroAugusto Esqueci das aspas, modifiquei a resposta já.

Comment: Matheus Ribeiro, muito obrigado cara. Perfeito. Com os seus exemplo usando o LIKE eu já consigo fazer minhas consultas. Muito bom.

Comment: @RicardoMedeiros aceite a resposta então. Já que o nosso amigo te ajudou

Comment: @PedroAugusto, sou novo por aqui. Como eu aceito a resposta? Eu consigo fazer isso?

Comment: Abaixo das setas de "upvote" e "downvote" deve aparecer um V que pode ser marcado como verde. Clique nele, simples :)

Comment: @PedroAugusto muito obrigado